# Un-install network printer drivers from Windows 7 64 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, drivers, network-printer

I recently bought a NAS device that has print server functionality through USB. The printer was already installed and fully working on another Windows XP box, set up that box to see the printer over the network and it prints fine.

I tried to install the printer on my Windows 7 laptop (64-bit, Home Premium), but got the wrong drivers somehow, or it just refuses to work. I need to completely un-install the printer drivers and start from scratch.

Removing the printer (by going to the printers folder, right click and remove) does not actually un-install the drivers. It only removes the printer from active use. Even if I try to re-install new drivers it will load the old ones.

I have read a few things on the net that say to load up a device snap-in or something of the sort into Computer Management, but this seems to be valid for Windows 7 Pro or greater, the function everyone tells you to use isn't available in Home Premium.

Is there anything I can use to manage device driver files in Home Premium? I want to completely remove them from the computer.

Answer (score 1):

In home premium you will need an installed printer in "devices and printers" click to highlight any installed printer, Fax or Microsoft XPS doc writer and you will see an option appear at the top called "Print Server Properties", click that, go to the drivers tab and remove the drivers there if they are present.

W7 is pretty good about uninstalling everything when you do it they way you did, unlike other versions of Windows.